# How to create a listview containing months of the current year with checkboxes?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Months including the current month and the months to come from the current year should be displayed.

Comment: try to explain a bit better what you need please

Comment: Elaborate more with requirement.

Comment: With Joda-Time http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ and try with some FOR/WHILE statement?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley I need to display the upcoming months of the current year, in an array.

Comment: @jaydroider I need to display the upcoming months of the current year, in an array.

Comment: @GarimaNagpal You need to show us what you tried so far without that nobody will able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to answer:

In Android there is a class named `Calendar`. This is probably the best way to work with dates.

[this is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

You can istantiate a new istance by using

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getIstance();
```

This gives you a calendar with the info of the exact moment you istantiated it.

now, using

```
calendar.MONTH
```

You are getting the int of the current month.

All months are static values inside the Calendar class.

```
Calendar.JANUARY = 0
Calendar.FEBRUARY = 1
and so on...
```

So an array is a static thing:

```
String[] months = new String[12]();
months[0] = january;
....
```

or

```
String[] months = new String[]{"january", ...};
```

or

```
int[] months = new int[]{1,...};
```

If you want a list of months with checkboxes, please have a look at [how to use listview adapters](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

Hope this helps.